# jQuery append to existing element &nbsp;

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddaccount" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;
    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">User Account</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

I need to replace `&nbsp;` with `&nbsp; USER`

I try usint this jQuery code but it insert at then end of a tag not repalce existing `&nbsp;`:

```
$('a#ddaccount').append('USER');
```

So i need to get this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddaccount" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;USER
    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">User Account</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

And i get this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddaccount" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;
    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">User Account</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    &nbsp;USER
</a>
```

I try using first() after() i element but none works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is `append()` which simply adds the content to the end of the html content.

What you should be doing is get the entire html content and then in it replace `&nbsp;` with `&nbsp;USER` and then assign it back to the html.

**DEMO**

```js
$('a#ddaccount').html($('a#ddaccount').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '&nbsp;USER'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddaccount" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;
    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">User Account</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()`:

```js
$('a#ddaccount').html($('a#ddaccount').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '&nbsp;USER'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddaccount" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;
    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">User Account</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```